Overwrite Transition from outside in SwiftUI
I have a badge component with a built-in transition:
public struct BadgeView: View {

    ...

    public var body: some View {
        Text(stringValue)
            .background(.red)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: sideLength/2.0))
            .transition(.scale)
    }
}

Now I have a view modifier that adds a badge as an overlay to some view:
struct Badge: ViewModifier {

    ...

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                BadgeView(value: value)
                    .offset(x: -size/3.0, y: -size/3.0)
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear.onAppear {
                                size = geometry.size
                            }
                            .onChange(of: geometry.size) { newValue in
                                size = newValue
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0, anchor: UnitPoint(x: -0.3, y: -0.3)))
            }
    }
}

I try to overwrite the transition because the original transition moves to the center of the original position, not the offset position, of the badge.
Unfortunately, the overwrite has no effect – apparently SwiftUI uses the innermost transition and applies it. So I'm wondering how, for a SwiftUI component with a built-in transition, I can overwrite this transition from the outside when using this component?

How about just changing BadgeView? Pass the transition as a parameter to its init, and it can be .scale by default.

@Sweeper yeah this would be my fallback. It feels a bit strange and not very SwiftUI-y, though, as SwiftUI is more about composition and modifying views so I kind of expected that there is some other way. But this can be a solution for sure if nothing else works.

I don't think this is strange at all. A lot of things in SwiftUI is determined by the "innermost" view. All the environment values, for example, do this. transition uses _trait, which is a similar system to Environment.

Yes that's true. I still feel that, API-wise, it's in contrast to the idea of creating view modifiers and modifying views to the needs of their environment. Regardless, do you have any source I could read up on how transition works internally? Would be very interested about that, as I've never seen anything about it!

You can find some .swiftinterface files in the directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Modules/SwiftUI.swiftmodule. You can see the implementations of inlinable functions (e.g. transition). You can see that it calls _trait. Similar to environment keys, there are _ViewTraitKeys. This isn't really "how transitions work internally", just what the .transition modifier does (which isn't much).
